# object doesn't support this property or method for if in use ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

i have error "object doesn't support this property or method" in internet explorer 7.

```
function emrooz_sending_ajax(){
        textarea_data = $("#emrooztext").val();
        textarea_data = jQuery.trim(textarea_data);
        num_slider_today = $("#num_slider_today").val();
        if(textarea_data == "" || textarea_data == "خلاصه امروز شما در یک تا چند جمله..."){
        return alert("لطفا فرم را کامل کنید");
        }else{
        if(!window.ActiveXObject){
         try{
          xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
         }catch(e){
          xhr = false;
         }
        }else if(window.ActiveXObject){
         try{
          xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
         }catch(e){
          try{
          xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }catch(e){
          xhr = false;
          }
         }
        }
//...
```

in line 5 >>

```
if(textarea_data == "" || textarea_data == "خلاصه امروز شما در یک تا چند جمله...")
```

note: when a If conditional added in this code, a error added too!

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Better use

if(textarea_data.equals("")|| textarea_data.equals("خلاصه امروز شما در یک تا چند جمله..."))